# should I load jquery scripts with every page

Tags: php, jquery

In a project I am developing I use a layout file as a shell for the content for each of my pages, and the layout file calls my jQuery scripts.  The pages are all unique and they don't all use most of the scripts.  Is there a point at which loading all of the scripts for every page creates a performance burden or should I call them conditionally with a `switch` statement or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A balance of loading globally and selectively is best.  Once you start using jQuery, you'll probably want the core functionality on all pages.  But there may be some plugins that are only relevant on a few pages, and you may as well only load them there.

In addition to the way your pages are coded, you may want to use compression and browser caching to improve performance.  Both will reduce the bandwidth required for new and returning site visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the JQuery js on the main layout page. Then you might also need of some other plugins on selected pages then load that plugin JS on those pages only.

Loading all JS in main layout page will surely affect your loading and performance. So just keep JQuery js on main page and load other JS on respective pages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change a thing on your page, because if a user visits your main page (or another), the jQuery file is cached and doesn't need to load again.

BTW: This is also a reason why you should let google host you jQuery file, [as explained here](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)

Answer (score 0):

If you properly set up browser caching for these library scripts like jQuery, it does not really matter if you always load them.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the files into your pages and let each file load in its page